# Need help designing a HTTP POST parameter scheme - Android to PHP

Tags: php, android, http, post, http-post

I am in the process of developing an Android app which will rely heavily on a web service I am writing. The Android app will submit a `HTTP POST` request to a PHP web service. My initial idea for the parameter scheme was (I've left out params used for authentication and such):

[image: Table of Params]

But, this seems like too complex/inefficient of a parameter scheme to me. There must be a better way, but I am not terribly experienced with `HTTP POST` or web services in general, so I can't think of anything better. Using these parameters, I would need a **HUGE** `if/else if/else` or `switch` block to determine exactly what the request wants to do/get.

Here are my method definitions for my main controller/authenticator class on the PHP web service side:

```
public function validateUser($emailAddress, $password);
public function createUser($emailAddress, $handle, $passwordHash);
public function getUserByEmailAddress($emailAddress);
public function getUserByHandle($handle);
# the flags param is stuff like "Closes at night", "Hard to find", etc.
public function createLocation($title, $address, $lat, $long, $flags);
public function updateLocationFlags($locationId, $flags);
public function getLocationById($id);
public function getLocationByTitle($title);
public function getLocationByAddress($address);
public function getLocationsByNearby($lat, $long, $radiusInMiles);
public function upvoteLocation($locationId);
public function downvoteLocation($locationId);
public function destroyLocation($locationId);
# takenBy param is the handle of the user who took the photo
public function addImageToLocation($locationId, $takenBy, $imgAddress);
public function removeImageFromLocation($imgId);
public function getImagesByLocationId($locationId);
public function getImagesByTakenBy($takenBy);
public function upvoteImage($imgId);
public function downvoteImage($imgId);
```

And so I need a `HTTP POST` parameter scheme that will allow the PHP web service easily and efficiently determine what routine it needs to call and check for the required routine parameters appropriately. My proposed scheme seems unnecessarily complex to me, but I can't seem to think of any simpler solutions.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Symfony, you can use FOSRestBundle and their helpers, ymls and etc, to do the boilerplate work.

Take a look at:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html
http://allan-simon.github.io/blog/posts/create-a-rest-api-with-symfony2/
http://obtao.com/blog/2013/05/create-rest-api-in-a-symfony-application/

Comment: I am not really sure what Symfony is. How is a RESTful API different/better than just submitting normal `HTTP POST` requests?